# Remove tokens by document frequency

Tags: python, collections

I have this code:

```
# Remove words that appear less than X (e.g. 2) time(s)
from collections import defaultdict
frequency = defaultdict(int)
for text in texts:
    for token in text:
        frequency[token] += 1

texts = [[token for token in text if frequency[token] > 2] for text in texts]
```

Now does this filter away all tokens with a term frequency (total occurrences in all texts) below 2, or with a document frequency (total number of texts within with occurs once or more) below 2?

**EDIT:**

```
# Get term frequencies (how many times a term occurs no matter what)

from collections import Counter
termfrequency = Counter()
for text in texts:
    for token in text:
        termfrequency[token] +=1

texts = [[token for token in text if termfrequency[token] > 2] for text in texts]

# Get document frequencies (in how many documents a term exists > 0 times)

from collections import Counter
documentfrequency = Counter()
for text in texts:
    documentfrequency.update(set(text))

texts = [[token for token in text if documentfrequency[token] > 2] for text in texts]
```

Comment: What do *you* think, and why? Please tell us, and we'll have you spot the error (if there is one :)).

Comment: Well, it comes down to what `defaultdict` actually does. To my understanding, my code here sets up a dictionary which is then populated by the for-loop. The for-loop iterates over all `texts` and creates a defaultdict for each token in the text. I think it therefore calculates TF, but I want it calculate DF.

Comment: Have a look at nltk, it's python library for natural language processing over large document collections. It includes information retrieval functionality like tf and idf.

Comment: @textnet: Your reasoning is exactly right. If you want to compute a separate frequency for each document, you need to clear `frequency` between documents (by, for example, creating a new defaultdict).

Comment: @NPE Not really a separate frequency for each document, but the number of documents in the whole collection that a word occurs, no matter how many times it occurs within any specific document.

Answer (score 0):

> [I would like to compute] the number of documents in the whole collection that a word occurs, no matter how many times it occurs within any specific document.

Here is one way to do it:

```
from collections import defaultdict
frequency = defaultdict(int)
for text in texts:
    for token in set(text):
               # ^^^ set() only keeps one occurrence of each word
        frequency[token] += 1

texts = [[token for token in text if frequency[token] > 2] for text in texts]
```

There is nothing wrong with using a `defaultdict` here. However, it is worth noting that the `collections` module has a class that's even more suitable for the task at hand. It is called [`Counter`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.Counter):

```
from collections import Counter
frequency = Counter()
for text in texts:
    frequency.update(set(text))
texts = [[token for token in text if frequency[token] > 2] for text in texts]
```

Comment: Your code looks good: It sets up the dictionary (like a counter). Then goes through all texts, looks only at the unique words and adds to the dict and/or increases the counter each time a word occurs. Would `Counter` simplify this in any way?